# Dynamics CRM - send search from web form?

Tags: search, iframe, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I was wondering if it´s possible to send a search term to Dynamics CRM from a web form?

I have an PHP web page that has an search (input) field and once submitted the page refreshes with a few iframes. In one fram I have the Dynamics CRM "Acounts" loaded, but don´t know how to send the variable to the search field in Dynamics.

Is this possible without making changes to Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, I´ve noticed that this is possible in Dynamics CRM 2012.